# How do I create a list or an array of objects in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm a .net programmer vb & c#, but I can't seem to figure out how to get my objects into a list or array in PHP.

```
var mylist = new List<myobject>();

mylist.add(myobject1);
mylist.add(myobject2);
```

What I have tried.
Products being a property for a collection of `orderitems`:

```
$this->Products = getOrderItems();

public function getOrderItems()
{
    $items = array();
    $count = 0;

      // connect to db, query.....

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
        $count++;
        $items[$count] = ($row);
    }
    echo 'Count of Order Items...' . $count;

    return $items;
}
```

Am I even close?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$items = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    $items[] = $row;
}
echo 'Count of Order Items...', count($items);
```

Comment: Will this increment for every row that is fetch so at the end all the rows are in $items?

Comment: It also looks like i'm have issues using $this->Products = getOrderItems(); 

Is that legal in php?

Comment: It depends on what $this is and whether it has the var $Products.

Answer (score 6):

- `$this->Products = getOrderItems();` is legal in PHP, but it refers to the (global) function `getOrderItems()` instead of the class method. class methods and variables always have to be prefixed with `$this->` (or `self::`, if they're static vars) when called from inside the class.
  in your sample-code, you have that wrong. getOrderItems is defined as class method, but your call is not `$this->`-scoped, thus php assumes a function. it should throw an `function not found`-error.
- the `[]` notation adds an element to the end of an array.
- the index of the first element in your sample code is 1 (isn't that the standard case for VB?). php normally starts at 0 - though it's possible (because php-arrays are not real arrays) to start at arbitrary indices i'd recommend to stick with zero.
- `mysql_fetch_array` is an *ancient* way of working with mysql. nowadays you're better of with mysqli or (even better) PDO.
- > (...) a list or array in php.

  lists, arrays, stacks, whatever: in php everthing is an ordered map (misleadingly called array):

  > [PHP: Arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php): An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

**update:**

sorry, i haven't got enough time right now to explain the finer nuances of [pdo](http://www.php.net/pdo)/[mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) over [mysql](http://www.php.net/mysql).

so here are just the basics:

- **oop:** pdo and mysqli are object oriented (tough mysqli got functional aliases)
- **prep statements:** most important: pdo/mysqli got prepared statements. that means, you first prepare the query with placeholders once, then fill in the values later (without the need to prepare the query a second time). this approach has 3 obvious advantages:

  - **performance:** it's faster, because the database only has to analyze, compile and optimize the query once *(at least with complex queries)*
  - **security:** no need for quoted strings (happens automatically!), making sql-injection attacks harder
  - **maintainability:** the logic and data part of the query are separated, thus easier to read and you don't have to do a lot of string concenation
- **driver driven:** pdo is not database specific. there are several supported db-systems, making it easier to port your code to other db-backends *(but it's not an db-abstraction layer like ODBC, so the SQL still has to be compatible)* and increasing reusability

of course, there's a lot more to it

Comment: Wow man what a great response! So can you elaborate more on mysqli and PDO?

Answer (score 1):

What orlandu63 posted is correct - using `$items[] = $row` means that $row is appended numerically as the next element of $items.

Another option is that if there's an id field in $row, you can do `$items[$row->id] = $row;`, which has the advantage of indexing your array and making it easier to find a given item.

I really suggest reading through http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, which will explain to you some of the cool things PHP allows with arrays.